# Can I see what happens behind the Windows (Dell, in that case) boot logo?

Tags: windows, boot, debug

Since something(TM) happened with my laptop (Dell Latitude E6440) yesterday (I suspect a Windows Update, but who knows), my Windows 10 Pro installation (17134.1, if that matters) does not boot any longer. Basically, during bootup I saw *only* a Dell logo indefinitely, with nothing else happening beside some initial hard disk activity.

First, I suspected the Windows Boot Manager was broken. So I have recreated the EFI partition and configured bcdedit to always show the boot menu. Now, the Dell logo disappears at one point and I can see the boot menu entries etc. I configured just fine. So I believe I can see everything around the boot manager itself is working.

However, when I select my "Windows 10 Pro" in the boot menu and press enter, the Dell logo appears again, effectively hiding everything that may be happening. The disk is active for a second or two, until the system stops as before. I have activated `bootlog` for this boot menu entry, and I have also tried using the F8 menu to activate logging - but `%WINDIR%\Ntbtlog.txt` is simply not written. So the Windows boot process seems to stop before it ever reaches this point

Can I debug what happens behind the Dell logo? Can I turn it off somehow?

I also remember that earlier Windows version has a step-by-step (driver-by-driver) mode, where you have to confirm every single step of the boot process. Is this still around?

Comment: That step-by-step mode you're looking for is Safe Mode, and yes, it's still available in Windows 10

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator thanks, but I am not sure I agree. I started safe mode in a separate installation of Windows 10, and there was no step-by-step procedure at all. Note that I am not referring to "Safe mode with command line".

Comment: I too quickly glanced over the part where you *confirm* loading drivers! IIRC the last version of Windows that supported that was 98!

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator oh my, feels like yesterday... :)

Comment: Not sure if this is still relevant, but are you saying you are not happy with simply _seeing_ each driver that is loaded, which would allow you to find the point at which it stops? That option certainly exists in Windows 10.

Comment: @MilindR maybe I wasn't clear here: I would be happy to _see_ a list of loaded drivers (even after the fact), but `Ntbtlog.txt` is not written (I suspect the boot processed halts before that is started), and I know no other way to see the list of loaded drivers...

Comment: Unfortunately the option I was recalling does not work in Win8+ (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d9ffb308-a7d3-4554-b468-92fce9789087/quotos-boot-informationquot-sos-option-in-windows-8-has-no-effect?forum=w8itprogeneral and https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1aa84b13-77d0-4ee6-8f41-9612727f0447/w2k12-show-os-bootinformation?forum=winserver8gen). Damn...